# How to perform full text search on PostgreSQL via Loopback?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, search, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Loopback for my application — I need to perform a full text search on tables in the database. I've read the [PostgreSQL documentation on text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html) but I'm not sure how to make these queries from Loopback. Since [native SQL is discouraged](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html) I'm wondering if there is an official way to make a query like this:

```
SELECT title
FROM pgweb
WHERE to_tsvector(title || ' ' || body) @@ to_tsquery('create & table')
ORDER BY last_mod_date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The reason I want to do a search query from Loopback is to incorporate other Loopback features, such as including related models, operation hooks, etc.